# Big O Notation with function composition

Tags: c, math, big-o

I'm trying to determine the Big O notation of the following function

```
public static int f10(int n)
{
    return f1(n*n*n)
}
```

Where f1() is given by:

```
public static int f1(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sum++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sum++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I can see that O(f1) is O(n^2), but when we call f10, does this become O(n^6) because the size of n is being cubed before calling f1?

I understand the complexity of f1 is not changing from it's own perspective, but is it from f10's perspective of 'n'?

Comment: When calling a function with a `n^3` input, you're missing the whole point of complexity limits. I'd still consider it as O(n^2)

Comment: Big-O notation is relative to the amount of operations, not directly the input number. That is, O(n^2) is always O(n^2) for any and all n. Calling a function with n^3 has nothing to do with time complexity.

Comment: Complexity of f1 is always `O(n^2)`, that's clear. However, the complexity of f10 is indeed `O(n^6)`, because it relies on f1 invoked with argument `n^3`. Imagine that f1 is inlined, you would have two nested for loops in f10, each with `n^3` iterations, and that is `O(n^6)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse `f1()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) -> O(n)

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) -> O(n)

for (n-times) { O(n) } -> O(n^2)
```

So `f1()` is O(n^2). It's just two nested loops. But because `f1()` is called with n^3, make `f10()` indeed O(n^6).

However, the above complexity order is theoretical. In practice it may depend on how you call `f10()` and/or what optimizations the compiler makes. A smart C compiler could replace `f1()` with a simple and O(1) arithmetic expression.

Then, having `f1()` reduced to an expression, the compiler could replace calls like `f10(42)` with the result, doing all calculations at compile-time.

Do you see what I mean; how would you simplify `f1()` to a simple O(1) expression?

Answer (score 2):

Complexity of `f1` is always `O(n^2)`, that's clear. However, the complexity of `f10` is indeed `O(n^6)`, because it relies on `f1` invoked with an argument `n^3`. For the sake of simplicity, imagine that `f1` is an inlined function. Body of `f10` would then look like this:

```
public static int f10(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n^3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n^3; j++)
            sum++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n^3; j++)
            sum++;
        for (int j = 0; j < n^3; j++)
            sum++;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Now it is easy to deduce - two levels of nested loops, each with `n^3` iterations -> `O(n^6)`. If you are still not convinced, try to see how the running time of `f10` increases with increased input:

```
n = 1 -> 3 iterations

n = 2 -> 8 * 3 * 8 = 3 * 2^6 iterations

n = 3 -> 27 * 3 * 27 = 3 * 3^6 iterations
....
n = k -> k^3 * 3 * k^3 = 3 * k^6 iterations
```